# how to properly install latest version of `npm` compatible with nodejs` inside a python virtualenv

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, npm-install

ubuntu 16.04

I want to install npm 5.4.2 node 8.7.0. 
i.e when I do `npm --version` it should say `5.4.2` and doing `node --version` should say 8.7.0.

Step1:

```
sudo apt install nodejs npm
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Step 2:

```
(setup) vivek@vivek:~/PROJECT$ sudo npm install -g n
    /usr/local/bin/n -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/n/bin/n
    + n@2.1.8
    updated 1 package in 1.045s
    (setup) vivek@vivek:~/PROJECT$ sudo n stable

        install : node-v9.0.0
          mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/9.0.0
          fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v9.0.0/node-v9.0.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
    ######################################################################## 100.0%
      installed : v9.0.0
```

Step 3:

```
(setup) vivek@vivek:~/PROJECT$  npm --version
3.5.2  

(setup) vivek@vivek:~/PROJECT$ sudo apt-get install npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
npm is already the newest version (3.5.2-0ubuntu4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Q.1 Why does it install 3.5.2 say it is the latest version ,when the current version is ~ 5.x.x or so.
Q.2 Why does it install node v9.0.0 when it is clearly not compatible with npm current releases.
 (https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19019)

So far the workaround I found was to do :

```
# Complete Un-install
sudo apt-get purge nodejs npm
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update



  # Fresh install
    sudo npm install -g npm
(setup) vivek@vivek:~/PROJECT$  npm --version
5.5.1
```

Running the same set of commands above in `Step 1 & 2`, all other teammates get the versions npm 5.4.2 and node 8.7.0 installed by default, but not for me. This is driving me mad.  Because the wrong versions are being installed, and on top of that they are not compatible.

Update: trying https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

failed with :

```
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
[sudo] password for vivek: 

## Installing the NodeSource Node.js v8.x repo...


## Populating apt-get cache...

+ apt-get update
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2  InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2  InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2  Release [574 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2  Release [574 B]
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                  
Ign:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                          
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]                                                                                                           
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                    
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]                                
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                            
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]                                                                  
Hit:12 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                               
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [653 kB]                         
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [618 kB]                                                           
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en [274 kB]                                               
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [307 kB]                                          
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [216 kB]                                               
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [8,076 B]                                       
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages [8,068 B]                                        
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [544 kB]                                         
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [517 kB]                                              
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [60.2 kB]                                          
Get:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en [221 kB]                                                                
Get:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [174 kB]                                              
Get:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [245 kB]                                                    
Get:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [16.2 kB]                                               
Get:27 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [15.3 kB]                                               
Get:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,888 B]                                        
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,328 B]                                                    
Get:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [4,588 B]                                                
Get:31 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [62.1 kB]                                                       
Get:32 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [51.4 kB]                      
Get:33 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [85.1 kB]                            
Ign:34 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                  
Ign:35 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial Release
Ign:36 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:37 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:38 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:39 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:40 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:41 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:42 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:36 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:37 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:38 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:39 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:40 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:41 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                                     
Ign:42 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                                                                        
Ign:36 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                            
Ign:37 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages                                                                                                             
Ign:38 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages                                                                                                              
Ign:39 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US                                                                                                         
Ign:40 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en                                                                                                            
Ign:41 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                                     
Ign:42 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                                                                        
Ign:36 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                            
Ign:37 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages                                                                                                             
Ign:38 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages                                                                                                              
Ign:39 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US                                                                                                         
Ign:40 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en                                                                                                            
Ign:41 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                                     
Ign:42 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                                                                        
Ign:36 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                            
Ign:37 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages                                                                                                             
Ign:38 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:39 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:40 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:41 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:42 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:36 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:37 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:38 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:39 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:40 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:41 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:42 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Fetched 4,395 kB in 17s (253 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Error executing command, exiting
```

Comment: What APT repositories do you have?

Comment: How do I check `the apt repositories I have` and are these the ones installed inside the virtualenv or outside of the virtual env?

Comment: along with `nodejs and npm` , inside virtual env I also install the following  `sudo apt install -y python-pip python-dev python-virtualenv postgresql wget libpq-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libffi-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libjpeg8-dev libfreetype6-dev pkg-config sox ffmpeg awscli libsox-fmt-mp3 nodejs build-essential openjdk-8-jdk mercurial screen npm vagrant virtualbox python-tk`

Comment: Have you tried `npm update -g npm`? After you get `npm` from your Ubuntu package manager, I would use `npm` to directly update itself.

Comment: @scorpiodawg 
here : https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally 

it says :  `To upgrade, run: [sudo] npm install npm@latest -g ` . I'm doing something similar in step 2. 
How is ^ different from your suggestion : `npm update -g npm` .

Comment: @scorpiodawg I tried your suggestion : `sudo npm update -g npm` but it still shows `3.5.2` as the version.

Comment: Python is unrelated to the problem. Virtualenv is not controlling NPM. Did you read how to install Node on Ubuntu? https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Comment: I tried that too. please see updated question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using using the following after completely removing old files leftover by previous installation. The best way to install node now is nvm, apt has too much issues.

```
//Remove node again
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs npm

//Remove any leftover files that gives version issues
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp /opt/local/bin/node opt/local/include/node /opt/local/lib/node_modules 

//Install nvm, this will install npm 5.4
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.6/install.sh | bash

//To uninstall a node version 
//nvm uninstall <version>

nvm install 8.7.0

nvm use 8.7.0

//check with 
node -v
npm -v
```

Comment: `dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove nodejs which isn't installed`
`dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove npm which isn't installed` however `npm -v` still shows 5.5.1 and `node -v` shows `v9.0.0` please advise.

Comment: Probably it was uninstalled by one of the previous commands that was used. But it should work now.

Comment: after following above steps, in case I want to uninstall nvm npm node,  how would I do that?